# Original Price is not sets in programmatically order

Tags: sales-order, quote, items

I try to place order programmatically but i have many problems during add items but now i have only one problem.

$produt is my product , $qoute is my qoute.

```
$item = $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
$item->setPrice(5);
$item->setBasePrice(5);
$item->setCustomPrice(5);
$item->setTaxPercent(0);
$item->setTaxAmount(0);
$item->setBaseTaxAmount(0);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(5);
$item->setRowTotal(5);
$item->setBaseRowTotal(5);      
$item->setPriceInclTax(5);
$item->setBasePriceInclTax(5);
$item->setRowTotalInclTax(5);
$item->setBaseRowTotalInclTax(5);       
$item->save();
```

After set this all thing in quote item i miss one field in order_item table that is original_price .I have no idea what field in quote assign to it.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Jaideep, I have the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: nope, actually i have to stop this work for some reason.but i remember there is one column in database for this "original Price" with very different name if you can set value  that column value after order place maybe solve your problem.