# How to set original price when order is placed programmatically in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have the same issue mentioned in [Original Price is not sets in programmatically order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79710/original-price-is-not-sets-in-programmatically-order), since it is not answered i am posting it again.

When i am placing order programmatically original price is not getting set in sales_flat_order_item table.

[image]

The following is the code snippet for place order which  have used

```
                $quotePayment = $quote->getPayment();
                $convertQuote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
                $order        = $convertQuote->addressToOrder($quote->getShippingAddress());
                $orderPayment = $convertQuote->paymentToOrderPayment($quotePayment);


                $order->setBillingAddress($convertQuote->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getBillingAddress()));
                $order->setShippingAddress($convertQuote->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getShippingAddress()));


                $order->setPayment($convertQuote->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment()));

                foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
                    $orderItem = $convertQuote->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem);
                    if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
                        $orderItem->setParentItem(
                            $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getParentItem()->getId())
                        );
                    }
                    $order->addItem($orderItem);
                    echo json_encode($orderItem->getData());exit;
                }

                $order->place();
                $order->save();


                //$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,true)->save();

                        Mage::dispatchEvent(
                        'checkout_submit_all_after',
                        array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote)
                    );

                        Mage::dispatchEvent(
                        'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
                        array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote)
                    );
```

Any help to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I as checked your code it seems that quote is already available with you so you can use below code to create order from already available quote object.

```
try {
    /*
      pass quote object in parameter to create order from quote 
    */
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();

    echo 'Order Id: ' .$increment_id. ' has been successfully created.';

} catch (Exception $e) {
   Mage::logException($e);
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me where exactly i should add this code?

Comment: in place of the above code if you have quote is already exists.

Comment: Okay, Thank you :)